# Unable to change select options populated via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have a few drop down menus that, when the right combination of values is selected, another drop down is populated. However, once the third drop down is populated, I'm unable to change the selection and the only option I can select is the first. The dropdown does not change to any other options I select. I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$('select').on('change', function() {
  var firstValue = $('#firstSelection').val();
  var secondValue = $('#secondSelection').val();

  if (firstValue == 1 && secondValue == 2) {
    $('#thirdSelection').html('<option>You</option>' +
      '<option>Have</option>' +
      '<option>Selected</option>' +
      '<option>The</option>' +
      '<option>Right</option>' +
      '<option>Options</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="firstSelection">
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="secondSelection">
  <option value='1'>One</option>
  <option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="thirdSelection"></select>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rV9Kz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your third `select` list doesn't retain its selected value because it gets repopulated when *any* select list is changed (including the third one).

I suggest giving the first two lists a class and responding only to lists with that class:

```
<select id="firstSelection" class="update">
    <option value='1'>One</option>
    <option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="secondSelection" class="update">
    <option value='1'>One</option>
    <option value='2'>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="thirdSelection"></select>
```

```
$('select.update').on('change', function () {
    var firstValue = $('#firstSelection').val();
    var secondValue = $('#secondSelection').val();

    if (firstValue == 1 && secondValue == 2) {
        $('#thirdSelection').html('<option>You</option>' +
            '<option>Have</option>' +
            '<option>Selected</option>' +
            '<option>The</option>' +
            '<option>Right</option>' +
            '<option>Options</option>');
    }
});
```

[Working Example (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/rV9Kz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are triggering the event off `$("select").change()` any time **any** of the selects change (including the third one) you are repopulating the third one which is forcing the first option to be selected.

All you have to do is change the selector for your event trigger from

```
$('select').on('change', function () {
```

to

```
$('#firstSelection, #secondSelection').on('change', function () {
```

and it will work as intended.

Here is [a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rV9Kz/2/)